# Autocomplete Typeahead w/ Multiple Values - APEX 21.1

Tags: oracle-apex

I would like to add a page item that looks like a textbox and can store one of more office codes. As the user types in this textbox, it performs a typeahead search and displays a list of the office codes filtered off of what has been typed. When the user selects an office code, it is added to the textbox and the user can then repeat the process and search/enter another office code.

I'm looking for similar functionality to the 'Tags' input field here on stack overflow when submitting a question. Or similar to the Bootstrap typeahead.

I have setup a `Text field with autocomplete` and this works exactly how I want, but the missing feature I'm after is being able to add multiple values or office codes (comma delimited would work).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle APEX 19.2 introduced a reworked popup LOV item type, that will allow you to do exactly that. It has both search-as-you-type and multiple value functionality. It can be configered to be displayed inline (looking almost like a classic select list) or as a modal dialog.

It may be inspired by the former `SELECT2` plugin item type, that was really popular.

It is quite self-explanatory, but here is a video I found that gives a nice overview:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTeB7pMtsGI